# how to loop argument in sh shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I know "for loop" can be used to go through all arguments. But for my code, I would prefer

```
i = 1
if [ ${$i} == xx] ; then
 xxx
fi

((iArg++))

if [ ${$i} == xx] ; then
 xxx
fi
```

Oberviously, ${$i} is not working. How shall I make it correct?

I used to write csh by using

```
$argv[$i]
```

Got to use sh shell now. Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of this very difficulty, argument parsing is typically done by using `$1` and `shift`. A typical loop might look like:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -a) echo "-a";    shift 1;;   # option with no argument
        -b) echo "-b $2"; shift 2;;   # option which takes argument, use $2
        -c) echo "-c";    shift 1;;
    esac
done
```

That said, the way to do indirect variable names is with `!`, as in:

```
${!i}
```